# Can I connect the KAA server with an Active Directory group for authentication & authorisation?

Tags: security, authentication, directory, authorization, kaa

When different app SDKs are contacting the KAA server, I want to send a AD user from the SDKs which should be authenticated & authorized at the KAA server level.  Is that doable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kaa provides ability to use one of existing or custom Credential Service(s). See [Custom implementation of Credential Service](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Devices-provisioning-and-registration/#custom-implementation-of-credentials-service) documentation page for more details.